# Check if product category is top level or have no child-categories

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I have 3 levels of product categories on my site:

Top Level (who has child categories but no parent category)
Mid Level (who has both parent category and child categories)
End Level (who has parent category but no child categories)

I want to be able to check if a category has parent category and if it has child categories, in order to decide if echo a specific object on the category page or not.

How do I do that?

Tnx Ahead!

Comment: What's holding you up?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: lol - forgot to put the question - edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, Try the below,

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); // get current term

$parent = get_term($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') ); // get parent term

$children = get_term_children($term->term_id, get_query_var('taxonomy')); // get children

if(($parent->term_id!="" && sizeof($children)>0)) {

    // has parent and child

}elseif(($parent->term_id!="") && (sizeof($children)==0)) {

    // has parent, no child

}elseif(($parent->term_id=="") && (sizeof($children)>0)) {

    // no parent, has child

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either can detect the parent or child by using this function "cat_is_ancestor_of()"
or else you can use "get_ancestors()".

Hope this helps to fix your need.

Comment: I'm not looking for the parent or the child - I'm looking to see of it has one. maybe it's a logical thing that I don't get yet...?